# Protocol extension to be applied to several types

Tags: swift, protocols, swift4, swift-protocols

I have a protocol, for instance:

```
protocol P {
    func foo()
}
```

It is possible to make default implementation for some type:

```
extension P where Self == Int {
    func foo() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

But how to have same default implementation for several types? Like this:

```
extension P where Self == Int or Self == Float {
    func foo() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can unite the types with another `protocol` (for example `HasDefaultFoo`).  This allows the types to decide when adopting the protocol if they want the default implementation.

```
protocol P {
    func foo()
}

protocol HasDefaultFoo {
    func foo()
}

extension Int: P, HasDefaultFoo { }
extension Float: P, HasDefaultFoo { }

extension P where Self: HasDefaultFoo {
    func foo() {
        print(self)
    }
}

extension Double: P {
    func foo() {
        print("I provide my own foo()")
    }
}
```

**Example:**

```
5.foo()
(5.5 as Float).foo()
5.5.foo()
```

Output:

> ```
> 5
> 5.5
> I provide my own foo()
> ```